# How to disabled button on Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

this first part working fine.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="mySwitchone=true">
<p>
    <button ng-disabled="mySwitchone">Click Me!</button>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitchone"/>Button
</p>
<p>
{{ mySwitchone }}
</p>
</div>
```

But do not work on second part. What's wrong with this code. Can anyone tell me.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="myTest=true">

<p>
    <button ng-disabled="myTest"> Click me</button> 
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myTest"/>Button
</p>
<p>
    {{ myTest }}
</p>

</div>
```

Comment: It does work? http://jsfiddle.net/b6yjgfvz/1/

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No error in console. I want to work both part one html page. But first part work fine. but second part not work.

Comment: @brannmar  I think he has problem when having both of the divs

Comment: You have both div in the same page ? If yes, remove `ng-app` on the second div. You can't declare this multiple times.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan aha I see. The problem is that you have multiple ng-app on one page. It can be solved by doing this. http://jsfiddle.net/b6yjgfvz/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem you can use multiple ng-app. Try this bellow way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<body>


<div  ng-init="mySwitchone=true">
<p>
    <button ng-disabled="mySwitchone">Click Me!</button>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitchone"/>Button
</p>
<p>
{{ mySwitchone }}
</p>
</div>

<div  ng-init="myTest=true">

<p>
    <button ng-disabled="myTest"> Click me</button> 
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myTest"/>Button
</p>
<p>
    {{ myTest }}
</p>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[See more](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_htmldom.asp)

Comment: Linking to w3schools is generally a poor resource,  linking to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp or some better resource would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your code needs to be-

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="mySwitchone=true;myTest=true">
<p>
<button ng-disabled="mySwitchone">Click Me!</button>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitchone"/>Button
</p>
<p>
{{ mySwitchone }}
</p>

<p>
<button ng-disabled="myTest"> Click me</button> 
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myTest"/>Button
</p>
<p>
{{ myTest }}
</p>

</div>
```